Where to begin learning?
I am a designer that has recently discovered this very interesting side of typesetting and typography design.
Through this discovery, I am however very lost, as the family of all the programs combined have built (thanks to you all) a large source material to learn and experiment from.
Where would you suggest is the best area to start learning? As I understand, TeX and LaTeX are typesetting programs that use typefaces from/created in Metafont (I may be very wrong, please correct me if so).
Considering my lack of knowledge and abundance of respect for this community, what do you suggest is the best way to start learning the METAFONT, TeX and all the other (and/or necessary) programs?
Where do I start...?

you don't need to learn metafont (virtually no one uses that) but to learn latex you can browse this site or use a tutorial sch as https://www.learnlatex.org/ which is available in several languages.

Welcome! What type of documents do you want to create? Also, do you plan to use LaTeX, ConTeXt or something else?

What @DavidCarlisle said. but if you are interested in metafont per se, you might want to look at metapost which uses similar methods for graphics, but is not confined to bitmaps. however, unlike metafont, it isn't used for fonts. (I suppose it should be used for 'posts' if the naming was logical, but I'm not sure what that might mean ....)

@cfr meta-PostScript I guess

Welcome. // I suggest to get a book introducing LaTeX. There are many good ones out there, presenting all you need for a start. Later you'll look at packages from ctan.org anyway, which extend LaTeX or overcome shortcomings.

@DavidCarlisle meta-afterthought?
